# When does the on-start element of spring webflow execute?

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am new to Spring Webflow. My doubt is, when does the  element get executed in flow xml file? Is it a part of the first view-state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a ton of actual information about this, but it is executed when the whole flow begins, right after the variables and inputs are created

https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/actions.html#action-on-start

Comment: So it is executed even before entering the first state(may be first view-state)?